# Decorated generator function

Tags: python, generator, decorator

I have a decorator:

```
def remediation_decorator(dec_mthd):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return dec_mthd(*args, **kwargs)
        except (KeyError, HTTPError) as err:
            print(f'error = {err}... call the remediation function')
    return new_func
```

Inside the generator function, another function is called to raise specific exceptions under certain conditions:

```
def check(number):
    if number == 1:
        raise HTTPError
    if number == 2:
        raise KeyError
```

This generator function is decorated like so:

```
@remediation_decorator
def dec_mthd_b(number):
    check(number)
    for i in range(0,3):
        yield i+1
```

When an exception is raised by the check function, the decorator's except is not hit.

```
[ins] In [16]: dec_mthd_b(1)
Out[16]: <generator object dec_mthd_b at 0x10e79cc80>
```

It appears to behave like this because it's a generator function - from [Yield expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr):

> When a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a generator.

(I wonder whether to take this in the literal sense 'it returns the iterator first irrespective of other logic in the function', hence why check() does not raise the exception?)

and,

> By suspended, we mean that all local state is retained, including the current bindings of local variables, the instruction pointer, the internal evaluation stack, **and the state of any exception handling**.

Have I understood this correctly? Please can anyone explain this further?

Comment: I don't know the answer unfortunately but I have bookmarked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) for myself as I always forget how `yield` and generators work. Maybe it will be of some use.

Comment: There is an excellent overview [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do). Reading this through again, I think it gives a pretty good explanation of what is happening here as it says 'when you call the function, the code you have written in the function body does not run'

Comment: next(dec_mthd_b(1)) raises the desired exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you got it.
`@remediation_decorator` is a Syntactic Sugar in python for decorators. I'm going to use the verbose(?) form:

```py
def dec_mthd_b(number):
    check(number)
    for i in range(0, 3):
        yield i + 1

dec_mthd_b = remediation_decorator(dec_mthd_b)
```

What does this line do ? `remediation_decorator` is your decorator, it gives you the inner function, in your case `new_func`.

What is `new_func` ? It is a normal function, when you call it, it runs the body of the function.

What will return from `new_func` ? `dec_mthd(*args, **kwargs)`.

Here `dec_mthd` points to `dec_mthd_b` and it is a **function** again. But when you **call** it, since `dec_mthd_b has` yield` keyword inside, it *gives* you back the generator object.

Now here is the point. The body of your inner function, here `new_func`, is executed without any problem. You got your generator object back. No error is raised...

```py
# this is the result of calling inner function, which gives you the generator object
gen = dec_mthd_b(1)

# Here is where you're going to face the exceptions.
for i in gen:
    print(i)
```

What will happen in the for loop ? Python runs the body of the `dec_mthd_b`. The error is raised from there...

So in order to catch the exceptions, you have two options, either catch it inside the `dec_mthd_b`, or in the last for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have understood it correctly. The below code will throw an exception. When a generator is created nothing gets executed. You need to fetch the next element, hence get the value from generator, then it will raise the exception.

```
g = dec_mthd_b(1)
next(g) #throws httperror
```

In fact thats how iteration is done, we repeatadly call next method, until IterationError exception is thrown.